# storm 0.10.0 cluster.xml configure

Tags: log4j2, apache-storm

in storm-0.10.0 when I config the cluster.xml, I use `${storm.home}/logs/${logfile.name}` like storm-0.9.0, but the value `${storm.home}` and `${logfile.name}` not identified, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4j2 has many different kinds of lookups. They are distinguished by their prefix. For system properties the prefix is `sys:`.

So try `${sys:storm.home}/logs/${sys:logfile.name}`.

See also http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html for more information.

Comment: ok,thank you,I have solved this problem,I find the problem in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1024 and use  ${sys:storm.log.dir}/${sys:logfile.name},thank you again

Comment: Can you close the question if this answer is a good solution? Thanks!